# Storing a compound dict in a client-side session

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm on my way to use server-side sessions, but then I figured out that they still rely on a client-side session, and so I'm trying to have a better grasp of the details of storing a compound, yet tiny, structure in the session.

We store a counter `i` in the session. At each of the first 3 requests, we insert in a dict `a` a new key:value pair.

On the third and subsequent reloads (requests), the code below gets stuck on the `elif session['counter']['i'] == 2:` condition. The third is never reached. Why?

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'KLMNOP'

@app.before_first_request
def ensure_session_is_initialized():
    if not session.has_key('a'):
        session['a'] = {}
    if not session.has_key('counter'):
        session['counter'] = {}
        session['counter']['i'] = 0

@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['counter']['i'] += 1

    if session['counter']['i'] == 1:
        session['a']['1'] = 'K'
    elif session['counter']['i'] == 2:
        session['a']['2'] = 'L'
    elif session['counter']['i'] == 3:
        session['a']['3'] = 'M'
    return render_template_string('''
    <body>
    {% for alpha in session %}
        KEY1: {{ alpha }}<br />
        {% for num in session[alpha] %}
            KEY2KEY2: {{ num }}:{{ session[alpha][num] }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </body>
    ''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Update**

thangtn found the answer, but it would also be nice to have a justification why the standalone code

```
session = {}
session['counter'] = {}
session['counter']['i'] = 0
for i in range(5):
    session['counter']['i'] += 1
print session['counter']['i']
```

prints `5` as we'd expect, yet the similar "compound dict" code in the view function requires the revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the session does not update the value of session['counter'] when session['counter']['i] == 1. That's why your if clause stop at session['counter']['i'] == 2. I haven't figured out why but your code works when I update 'i' by re-assigning value of session['counter']:

```
def index():
    i = session['counter']['i'] + 1
    session['counter'] = {'i': i}
    ...
```